# Did the code blocks' background color go slightly blue?

Tags: support, design

Did the code blocks' background color go slightly blue recently on the main site? Or am I crazy thinking it was a warmer gray?

Comment: Everything else turned slightly red.

Comment: Could be the lighting of your workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out it was over remote desktop. I suppose the compression is losing some of the detail or adding something else to it.

Answer (score 1):

The code block's current background color (on Stack Overflow) is `#eff0f1` - for humans, this is indistinguishable from `#f0f0f0` which is pure gray. So it is not slightly blue, and if you perceive this it is more likely due to your monitor.

I found an old screenshot where the background color is `#eeeeee`, so slightly *darker*, but not less blue.

[image]

Comment: Using archive.org, it seems like it was `#eee` before though.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I was just looking in Meta for some old pics as well :)

Comment: Old on left, new on right: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAWOt.png ... Or maybe the other way around, I forgot >_<